# В первом и последнем фрагменте не проигрывает звук

Tags: android

Хочу проигрывать звук в fragment. Написал так

```
public class ItemFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.pager_item, container, false);
        Bundle args = getArguments();

        this.getContext().startService(new Intent(this.getContext(), PlayerService.class));

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Написал сервис

```
public class PlayerService extends Service {
    public PlayerService() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        play();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    void play() {
        //Объект проигрывателя, который будет проигрывать звук на кнопке.
        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio);
        //Звук будет проигрываться только 1 раз:
        mp.setLooping(false);
        //Установка обработчика события на момент готовности проигрывателя:
        mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener()
        {
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
            {
                //При готовности к проигрыванию запуск вывода звука:
                mp.start();
            }
        });

        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener()
        {
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
            {
                mp.release();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Не проигрывается вообще аудио. Что не так сделал я?

Comment: Так может плеер весь в сервис вынести, а при переключении фрагментов просто сервису сообщать команды?

Comment: согласен с @VladimirParfenov перенесите проигрывание в сервис, и пусть фрагменты передают команды сервису что проигрывать

Comment: Где можно про сервисы почитать? Никогда не работал с ними